# how to center text inside hyperlink with border

Tags: css

I need the text to be completely in the center of the border.
It seems that it is a bit more down that it should be

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3FyF9/20/)

I have also tried removing the paragraph and added

```
<span>Register test</span> <br><span>my text 2</span>
```

But that didn't work either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try to change the padding on the `a.register` element?

Try something like this :

```
 a.register {
     padding: 18px 0 6px;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3FyF9/21/

Answer (score 2):

If your button only has one line of text, you can also use `height: 50px;` and `line-height: 50px;`